# Как распарсить такой json

Tags: python, json

Прошу знающих подсказать, человеским языком как распарсить такой json на python
Хочу понять принцип
Вот такой json у меня

```
{'count': 29,
 'ports': [
  {'ifName': 'Vl1'},
  {'ifName': 'Vl50'},
  {'ifName': 'Fa0/1'},
  {'ifName': 'Fa0/2'},
  {'ifName': 'Fa0/3'},
  {'ifName': 'Fa0/4'},
  {'ifName': 'Fa0/5'},
  {'ifName': 'Fa0/6'},
  {'ifName': 'Fa0/7'},
  {'ifName': 'Fa0/8'},
  {'ifName': 'Fa0/9'},
  {'ifName': 'Fa0/10'},
  {'ifName': 'Fa0/11'},
  {'ifName': 'Fa0/12'},
  {'ifName': 'Fa0/13'},
  {'ifName': 'Fa0/14'},
  {'ifName': 'Fa0/15'},
  {'ifName': 'Fa0/16'},
  {'ifName': 'Fa0/17'},
  {'ifName': 'Fa0/18'},
  {'ifName': 'Fa0/19'},
  {'ifName': 'Fa0/20'},
  {'ifName': 'Fa0/21'},
  {'ifName': 'Fa0/22'},
  {'ifName': 'Fa0/23'},
  {'ifName': 'Fa0/24'},
  {'ifName': 'Gi0/1'},
  {'ifName': 'Gi0/2'},
  {'ifName': 'Nu0'}
 ],
 'status': 'ok'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Всё, что есть в вашем `json` парсится так, если всё это лежит в переменной `jsn`:

```
print(jsn['count'], jsn['status'])
for port in jsn['ports']:
    print(port['ifName'])
```

Вывод:

```
29 ok
Vl1
Vl50
Fa0/1
Fa0/2
Fa0/3
Fa0/4
Fa0/5
Fa0/6
Fa0/7
Fa0/8
Fa0/9
Fa0/10
Fa0/11
Fa0/12
Fa0/13
Fa0/14
Fa0/15
Fa0/16
Fa0/17
Fa0/18
Fa0/19
Fa0/20
Fa0/21
Fa0/22
Fa0/23
Fa0/24
Gi0/1
Gi0/2
Nu0
```